# NaN When trying to print json values

Tags: javascript, json, nan

I was trying to parse a json which I got as a response of querying connections in linked in.

when I do JSON.stringify in an array as a whole I can see values in console.log
but when I try to take individual values inside array I get NaN.
Why can I not get Individual values when I can see the array as a whole.

here is the code

```
  var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
  var person = response.person[0];
```

in the above code I am getting data as a response of an ajax call

person is an array inside, I can stringify the array as a whole.
if I do

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(person));
```

I will get

```
{"id":"someId","first-name":"someName","last-name":"someName, DMC-E, DMC-D","picture-url":"https://soempicture"}
```

but When I try to take it individually

```
console.log(person.first-name);
```

I get NaN , and trying to strigify it results in Null

am I missing something, should I do string split to get the values?

Thank you

Comment: You're getting `NaN` because `person.first - name` is `undefined - undefined` which is not a number.

Answer (score 7):

You can't access the `first-name` property using period notation, as the name contains a dash.

The code will be interpreted as `person.first - name`, i.e. the `person.first` property minus the `name` variable.

Use the bracket notation for any property where the name can't be an identifier:

```
console.log(person['first-name']);
```

Comment: That said, if you have control over the JSON data, you could format the variables with `camelCase` or `snake_case` to make parsing easier.

Answer (score 0):

To access a key that contains characters that cannot appear in an identifier (`-`), use brackets, i.e.:

```
person["first-name"]
```